# Make a backup of a MariaDB database

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

I want to make a backup of a db in mariaDB, I've used the following statements but any work.

```
mysqldump -u root -p -databases messages > dbdescargada.sql
mysqldump -u root -p messages > dbdescargada.sql
mysqldump -u root messages > clients.sql
mysqldump --user='root' --add-locks messages messages > copia.sql
mysqldump --user='root' --add-locks messages messages > copia.sql
```

But all showed the same error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'statement' at line 1
```

[image]

I really need to do this backup cause I need to make important changes to the tables structures,
I'm using Xampp for Linux, Ubuntu 20.04
I know I can do it from localhost/phpmyadmin but I need also a code option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1) You are running it from mysql CLI. mysqldump is a shell command, not a mysql command.

2) Lose the `-` in `->` redirect to file - there is no minus before `>`

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is *--databases*

Your images suggests that you run the shell command in the *mysqlshell* that is **wrong**, yoz must run it in a normal command window bash msdods...

Please check the [parameters](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/)

```
mysqldump -u root -p --databases messages > dbdescargada.sql
```

Comment: you dpn' get a enter paaswprd?

Comment: I don have setted a password

Comment: then try it without -p

Comment: but even then there can not be your message

Comment: look at my anser and copy it exactly  yiu have a minus too much right before the >

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten that but I still have the same error, also when I type mysqldump --help get the same error, I don't know if it could be due to the xampp version (10.04.11-MariaDB Source Distribution)

Comment: exit mysql and run it cmd window, it id a shel cmmand nit a mysql command